# is there a platform that incorporates java code with regular text?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to create some sort of notebook for test preparations, that combines runnable java code with text such as titles, paragraphs, and explanations. currently, I'm using IntelliJ, but it isn't actually suited for writings other than code.
the ultimate solution would be some sort of Jupyter notebook, but from what I'm aware of, Jupyter is mostly for Python...
thank you for your help!

Comment: FYI the term you're looking for is Literate Programming.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca The term “notebook” has all but replaced the term “literate programming” where commonly used (i.e. in data science).

Comment: Note sure if its what you want but JetBrains has an Edu plugin for Intellij, useful for creating programming challenges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [this Java kernel for jupyter](https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava) before; it works well. It uses a JDK9 (or higher) jshell session behind the curtains and has some limited graphing functionalities built in.

Comment: thank you. do you know if there's a way of saving to my computer the notebook I've written online?

Comment: @HadarSharvit Jupyter runs locally and uses local files for notebooks. It starts a local webserver that you then access in your browser.

Comment: it's just that I've previously used this kernel and form some reason had a 403 forbidden error, so I was thinking maybe there's a way of backing up my files

Comment: @HadarSharvit of course there is. Everything is stored locally.

Comment: how can I find the folder with the files then?

Comment: @HadarSharvit When you run `jupyter notebook` or `jupyter lab`, any files you open or create will just be under the directory where you issued that command from.

Comment: I think you're referring to the jupyter on my computer, I was talking about opening it online via this link: https://mybinder.org/v2/gh/SpencerPark/ijava-binder/master

Comment: @HadarSharvit that's not meant for productive use, I think. It runs in docker images, and is meant for trying things out. You should really run it locally.

Answer (score 2):

> from what I'm aware of, Jupyter is mostly for Python

In fact, the project intentionally changed its former name from “IPython Notebook” to “Jupyter” to emphasise the fact that it’s *not* only for Python. [It supports kernels in many other languages](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/wiki/Jupyter-kernels), and [Java is one of them](https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava).